# How to set default selection of a dropdown by current hour?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I tried to make a timepicker for a website or find if jquery, Bootstrap etc. has any of their own (HTML's own uses AM/PM on Firefox and I couldn't change that), all I found were github projects and I can't use many dependencies like them for this project.

So my last solution was to add 2 dropdowns, 1 for current hour, 1 for current minute. Not the prettiest solution but it gets the job done.

```
<div class="col-lg-2">
    <select name="Hour">
    @{
        for(int i = 0; i < 24; i++)
        {
            @:<option value="@i">@i.ToString("D2")</option>
        }
    }
    </select>
    <b>:</b>
    <select name="Minute">
        @{
            for (int i = 0; i < 60; i++)
            {
                @:<option value="@i">@i.ToString("D2")</option>
            }
        }
    </select>
</div>
```

What I want to do is, I have a datepicker that sets default date to today, I want to do the same thing for these dropdowns, select current hour with first, current minute with second.

How can I do this?

(Any suggestions for a better clock/timepicker is also welcome but I find this one sufficient enough for my project and looks decent)

Comment: i think [this](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) helpful to you.

Comment: Like I said, I can't use github projects and have dependencies. Not to mention that is a datepicker, I need a timepicker, I am already using jQuery's datepicker which works well. Since I can't find a proper timepicker of Bootstrap's, jQuery's or HTML's own, I am using dropdowns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get time from date and reset your dropdown with time like this.

```js
var html = '';
for (var i = 0; i < 60; i++) {
  html += "<option value = '" + i + "' >" + i + "</option>";
}
$('#minute').append(html);
var d = new Date();
var n = d.getMinutes();
$("#minute").val(n);

var htm = '';
for (var j = 0; j < 24; j++) {
  htm += "<option value = '" + j + "' >" + j + "</option>";
}
$('#hour').append(htm);
var dt = new Date();
var h = dt.getHours();
$("#hour").val(h);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id='minute'>

</select>
<select id='hour'>

</select>
```

Comment: I already get dropdown options from Razor, so I assume all I need is var dt = new Date();
var h = dt.getHours();
$("#hour").val(h); part then?